# Translate theme only

Tags: translation

I think I'll lose my hair over this...

Here's my situation:

- I have a WP MU running on my server
- I have several sites in english

Now I want to add a blog in a different language under the same WP install, which will be using a twentyfourteen child theme, but I want everything else to stay in english.

I downloaded both the global WP and 2014 translations. I've tried to put one or both of these into my functions.php:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'nwnsablog', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}

add_filter( 'locale', 'my_theme_localized' );
function my_theme_localized( $locale )
{
    return 'sk_SK';
}
```

I put these files: `sk_SK.mo, sk_SK.po, [themename]-sk_SK.po, [themename]-sk_SK.mo` into the `languages` folder in my theme root. I also put the first two into the `languages` folder inside `wp-content`.

At this point, it's still all in english. If I change the `define('WPLANG', 'sk_SK');` line in wp-config, most of the strings are translated, but it also translates them outside the theme, which I don't want.

I could get to a point where a different part of strings was translated (I'm guessing they were theme specific), but I can't reproduce that. Anyway, it wouldn't be very useful, as it's only a halfway translation.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Your browser will define the language you are viewing in. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: Does twenty fourteen have some kind of browser detection? Anyway, even if it does, I want the page to be in slovak for everyone, as all the content will be in slovak.

Comment: I don't understand, if the content is in slovak already what does the theme have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back to this issue today and I solved it like a boss thanks to the [Zanto](http://wordpress.org/plugins/zanto/) plugin.

Just to recap, I was trying to translate the front-end of only one site from a multisite setup with the least possible hassle while leaving every other site unchanged.

All I did was copy the general WP language files into wp-content/languages and the translated theme language files into a languages folder inside the (parent) theme. I got those from the translated WP package I downloaded on the slovak WP website. Both are named sk_SK.po (and .mo).

By activating the plugin on the translated site, I could easily switch the language and that's all I needed. Great plugin!